# SQL set TRUE if 5+ or more consecutive hours with values below 0

Tags: mysql, sql, lag, lead

I want to check for 5+ consecutive hours hours were a given value is below 0, by setting a value (FiveConse) accordingly. Like shown in the table below

| Time | Value | FiveConse |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12:00 | 1 | False |
| 13:00 | -1 | True |
| 14:00 | -3 | True |
| 15:00 | -4 | True |
| 16:00 | -5 | True |
| 17:00 | -6 | True |
| 18:00 | -5 | True |
| 19:00 | 7 | False |
| 20:00 | 7 | False |

Currently i am using multiple lag/lead to look at each value, and the consecutive values. However this does not seem very efficient.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT `Time`, Value, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY `Time`) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Value < 0 ORDER BY `Time`) grp
    FROM test
)
SELECT `Time`, 
       Value,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) >= 5 FiveConsecutive
FROM cte
ORDER BY `Time`;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7476b715df0c69ac46736138366eec85

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `lead()` with some conditional logic:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(time, 4) over (order by time) as time_4,
             lead(time, 4) over (partition by (value < 0) order by time) as time_4_neg
      from t
     ) t
where time_4 = time_4_neg;
```

This compares the time value four rows ahead with the time value four rows ahead for negative values.  If they are the same, you have five negatives in a row.

You can actually do this with one window function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum( (value < 0) ) over (order by time rows between current row and 4 rows following) as cnt_neg_5
      from t
     ) t
where cnt_neg_5 = 5;
```